# Does the client application port need to be specified in a BlackBerry PAP push request?

Tags: blackberry

[This doc](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12029/Push_applications_for_the_BlackBerry_Enterprise_Server-Development_Guide--915141-1116110032-001-US.pdf) doesn't mention anything about indicating the port number anywhere in the PAP message. I'm assuming it looks it up by "source-reference" (aka Application Id). But the document also doesn't mention anything about the source-reference needing to be the app id, so I don't really trust what the doc does or doesn't specify. So my question is, does the port number of the app need to be included anywhere in a PAP push format request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no.

It's needed on the device side so a BlackBerry knows which port to listen on for the incoming messages. On the content publisher side, the port isn't required because it's assigned to you by RIM and their BPSS infrastructure will look up which one to use based on your application ID.

FYI, from the BlackBerry Support Forums, here's a [thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Push-Development/Help-with-a-standalone-push-request/m-p/491961/) with a dump of a PAP push request; the port isn't part of it.

It is a bit of a pain to do BlackBerry push development. The documents (both the developer's guides and the Javadoc) are quite sparse on detail.